# Is there a concept about the probability of probability?

Tags: probability

`P(bright light outside window, saucer-shaped object in sky) = very low`

This equation means: “The probability of observing bright lights outside the window and a saucer-shaped object in the sky is very low.”

However, is it reasonable that

`P(P(bright light outside window, saucer-shaped object in sky)) = sometimes`

represents some people who state that they have observed UFOs sometimes? In other words, is it meaningful to regard the probabilities themselves as events?

Comment: For me, it is. For example, if you assume that the parameter value $p$ of a Binomial distribution has a Betabinomial distribution, you can make inference on the value of a probability.

Comment: As I see it, the first would be `P(bright light and saucer in the sky)`, while the second is `P(bright light and someone thinking they saw a saucer in the sky)`.

Comment: To expand on what @FedericoTedeschi said - an example of inference about the value of a probability might be a statement like "There is a 10% probability that the probability of seeing a flying saucer outside your window is greater than 0.1%"

Comment: @da_miao_zi, I think the correct way to write your 2nd formula is: `P(P(bright light outside window, saucer-shaped object in sky) = sometimes)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say no. Even if, as @FedericoTedeschi proposes, you assume that p has a distribution, P(p) has no meaning, but P(p>e) may have one .. so I think you could look at something like `P(P(bright light outside window, saucer-shaped object in sky)>0.5) = sometimes` .. but if you really want to speak about the fact some people believe, you have to distinguish the probability P1 people gives to thoses events and P2 the one you use on to describe the distribution of theses probabilities, so

```
P2(P1(bright light outside window, saucer-shaped object in sky)>0.5) = 0.002
```

could have a meaning

Comment: Isn't the distinction you make entirely based on the continuous vs discrete distribution of P? So that, if @da_miao_zi had written: "f[(P(bright light outside window, saucer-shaped object in sky)) = sometimes]", it would have been correct?

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi I'm sorry but no .. continuous or discrete distribution of P (or P1 and P2, or p) doesn't change the fact that, in my comprehension,  P(p) has no meaning if p is not an event ..

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi and in you comment, when you put the last ) after "sometimes", it makes sense !

Comment: I'm not talking of P(p), but of f(P). Here, the event is: "P(bright light outside window, saucer-shaped object in sky)) = sometimes", that is a probability, thus a variable varying between 0 and 1. In a Betabinomial model to express the distribution of a Binomial parameter $p$, you have a situation like that. In fact, you define the distribution of a variable between 0 and 1, and such variable represents the $p$ parameter of a Binomial variable: https://towardsdatascience.com/beta-distribution-intuition-examples-and-derivation-cf00f4db57af

Comment: @FedericoTedeschi yes, I agree, that's why I said that when you put the last ")" after "sometimes" it makes sense

Comment: As you mentioned @MrSmithGoesToWashington, `P(p) has no meaning, but P(p>e) may have one`, is it because for each of individual `p`, `P(p)` is infinitely small, meaning the probability of any specific value is 0, but the range of continuous `p` values, corresponding a sum of `P(p)`  is not 0?

Comment: @da_miao_zi it really depends on what is p : if it is just a number, P(p) has no meaning, if it is an event, even if it's probablity is very small, or even null, P(p) has a meaning ..